# SSCollectionView Delegate Problems

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am having a problem with the `SSCollectionView` control, a subclass of `NSTableView` from the SSToolkit. For some reason, all delegates except for `- (SSCollectionViewItem *)collectionView:(SSCollectionView *)aCollectionView itemForIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` are called. Even though this delegate is `@required`, removing it will cause no exception either. And before you ask, yes the arrays below all have data in them.

I have checked if the data source/delegate becomes `nil` at any stage, but it doesn't, so I'm baffled.

Here's how I create the view:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSLog(@"ViewDidLoad");

    _titles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    _subtitles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    _thumbnails = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    _collectionView = [[SSCollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.frame];

    _collectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor scrollViewTexturedBackgroundColor];

    [_collectionView setDelegate:self];
    [_collectionView setDataSource:self];

    [self.view addSubview:_collectionView]; 

    [_collectionView reloadData];
}
```

This is called fine and the view appears - but with no data.

This method is never called:

```
- (SSCollectionViewItem *)collectionView:(SSCollectionView *)aCollectionView itemForIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"Delegate Called");

    static NSString *const itemIdentifier = @"itemIdentifier";

    SSCollectionViewItem *item = (SSCollectionViewItem *)[aCollectionView dequeueReusableItemWithIdentifier:itemIdentifier];

    if (item == nil) 
    {
        item = [[[SSCollectionViewItem alloc] initWithStyle:SSCollectionViewItemStyleImage reuseIdentifier:itemIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    item.textLabel.text = [_titles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    item.detailTextLabel.text = [_subtitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    item.imageView.image = [_thumbnails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return item;
}
```

I don't think this is a bug - did I miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This won't get called if there are no items in your collection view. Make sure the following `SSCollectionViewDataSource` method is implemented and returns a value greater than zero.

```
- (NSUInteger)collectionView:(SSCollectionView *)aCollectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSUInteger)section
```

Also, make sure you implement the following `SSCollectionViewDelegate` method as well so your items will be displayed correctly.

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(SSCollectionView *)aCollectionView itemSizeForSection:(NSUInteger)section
```

I would recommend using `SSCollectionViewController` if it is the only view in your view controller since it will take care of a lot of the glue code for you.

Comment: Wow! The developer answered :D I have both of these implemented and they don't return zero. To check, I have even implemented a log message that confirms that. Hence I am baffled.

Comment: I've done a bit of moving around and now i'm being told that I don't tell it the size of the items, even though I have implemented this delegate too. Odd.

Comment: I did get it to work now. But for cell styles, only SSCollectionViewItemStyleImage works, but I need subtitles. Why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add your `- (CGSize)collectionView:(SSCollectionView *)aCollectionView itemSizeForSection:(NSUInteger)section:`before `viewDidLoad`.. don't know why but it works for me this way

Comment: How do you mean? Set the delegate and data source in `init`?